# New In-App-Purchase not visible in Apple iTunes

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Since today I have a new version of my iOS-based mobile app in Apple iTunes including a new 3rd In-App-Puchase.

However I see all three IAPs in iTunes Connect, but not in Apple App Store. Only my first 2 IAPs are visible, not the latest one.

What is going on here? Am I supposed to wait some hours?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 possible reasons for inApp purchases not visible.

- First thing is inApp purchase will take some time to display on App store once its used. So it might take 6-8 hours & than it will be visible.
- Second & most important is on app store what we see is the list of  top in app purchases of that app. If you have just created new inApp purchase & its not sold yet than they will not show up.

Hope it will guide you.

Comment: Or it was not submitted at the same time as the app version

Comment: Hey @mayur  can you please take a look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37872798/new-in-app-purchase-are-not-displayed-in-the-itunes-app-product-page

Comment: @Unni take a look my answer there