# New In-App-Purchase are not displayed in the iTunes app product page

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, itunes-store

My app provides IAP for our users and We already have one product then, which is listed on the "Top In-App purchases" section in iTunes product page. I submitted the latest version which have two new products. The build successfully went live (almost 2 weeks back) and I was able to purchase the new two products as well. Also the iTunes metrics show the purchase of new products from the users. But it is not displayed under "Top In-App purchases". Only the first IAP is listed under that section.

iTunes purchase reports says that my first product has 5 times sales than the new two. Is that the reason new two products are not listed under Top In-App purchases".  Can I see the all IAP offered by my app anywhere in the iTunes app product page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 possible reasons for new inApp purchase not showing on iTunes under Top inApp purchases.

- First reason is if you have recently used inApp purchase it could take some time to show up on the Top inApp purchases section
- Second most important reason is that apple support team provided is "The In-App Purchases section of your app’s product page will contain the top In-App Purchases for the app only after a minimum purchase requisite has been reached. If the number of completed In-App Purchases doesn’t exceed the minimum threshold, this area will not appear"

In your case i think your new in App purchases are not enough used so that could be shown on iTunes on your product page.

I hope it will guide you.